# real analysis - subsequence of bounded sequence converges to $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ sup $a_k$

Tags: real-analysis

My professor proved that a subsequence of a bounded sequence $(a_k)$$_k$$_\to$$_\infty$ in $\mathbb R$ converges to $\limsup_{k\to\infty}$ $a_k$   this way:

Denote a* = $\limsup_{k\to\infty}$ $a_k$  and $b_n$$_j$ = sup {$a_k$ | k $\geq n_j$ }

Note that a* $\in \mathbb R$

$\forall j \in \mathbb N, \exists n_j$ such that |$b_n$$_j$ - a*| < $\frac{1}{j}$

$\Rightarrow$ a* - $\frac{1}{j}$ < $b_n$$_j$ < a* + $\frac{1}{j}$

$\Rightarrow$ $b_n$$_j$ - $\frac{1}{j}$ is not an upper bound of {$a_k$ | k $\geq n_j$}

$\Rightarrow$ $\exists k_j \geq n_j$ such that $a_k$$_j$ > $b_n$$_j$ - $\frac{1}{j}$
[Note that ($a_k$$_j$)$_k$$_\to$$_\infty$ is a subsequence]

We now have

(i) $a_k$$_j \leq$ $b_n$$_j$ < a* + $\frac{1}{j}$

(ii) a* - $\frac{1}{j}$ < $b_n$$_j$ < a* + $\frac{1}{j}$

(iii) $b_n$$_j$ - $\frac{1}{j}$ < $a_k$$_j$

so we have:

a* - $\frac{2}{j}$ < $a_k$$_j$ < a* + $\frac{1}{j}$

Since j is arbitrary,

|$a_k$$_j$ - a*| < $\frac{2}{j}$  $\forall j \in \mathbb N$

Hence $a_k$$_j \to$ a* as $j \to \infty$.

What I don't understand is that how does

$\forall j \in \mathbb N, \exists n_j$ such that |$b_n$$_j$ - a*| < $\frac{1}{j}$

this line hold? This line does not seem very clear to me. Why is j $\in \mathbb N$? And does it have to be $\frac{1}{j}$ or can it be like just j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of superior limit, $a^*=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$. So, if $\varepsilon>0$, you have $\lvert a^*-b_n\rvert<\varepsilon$ if $n$ is large enough. In particular, if $j\in\mathbb N$, there is some $n_j\in\mathbb N$ such that$$\lvert a^*-b_{n_j}\rvert<\frac1j.\tag1$$And yes, I could have written $j$ in $(1)$ instead of $\frac1j$ and it would still be true. But it would be useless too. Your lecturer uses $(1)$ to prove that there is a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges to $a^*$. Had he or she used $j$ instead of $\frac1j$ in $(1)$, that would not provide useful information to prove the statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot!